# Error message when using find -exec to copy files

Tags: bash, find

I use the [find](/questions/tagged/find) command to copy some files from one destination to another. If I do

```
$ mkdir dir1 temp
$ touch dir1/dir1-file1
$ find . -iname "*file*" -exec cp {} temp/ \;
```

everything works fine as expected, but if I do

```
$ mkdir SR0a temp
$ touch SR0a/SR0a-file1
$ find . -iname "*file*" -exec cp {} temp/ \;
> cp: `./temp/SR0a-file1' and `temp/SR0a-file1' are the same file
```

I get an error message. I do not understand this behavior. Why do I get an error by simply changing names?

Comment: The error message results from the command `cp ./temp/SR0a-file1 temp/SR0a-file1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `find` searchs in **SR0a/** folder at first, and then in **temp/**, and since you have copied into it the file, `find` founds it again in **temp/** folder. It seems that `find` uses crafty sorting so it just should be take into account on use of [find](/questions/tagged/find):

```
$ mkdir temp dir1 SR0a DIR TEMP
$ find . 
.
./TEMP
./SR0a
./temp
./dir1
./DIR
```

So in case the **dir1/** `find` founds the it at first, and this don't make such problems, let see the search sequence:

```
temp/
dir1/
```

When you search with **SR0a** the sequence is:

```
SR0a/
temp/
```

so found file is being copied into temp **before** searching it.

To fix it, either move **temp/** folder outside the current one:

```
$ mkdir SR0a ../temp
$ touch SR0a/SR0a-file1
$ find . -iname "*file*" -exec cp {} ../temp/ \;
```

or use pipe to separate find and copy procedures:

```
$ find . -iname "*file*" | while read -r i; do cp "$i" temp/; done
```

Comment: Then why does changing `SR0a` to `dir1` fix the problem?

Comment: I know how to fix the problem, but I still don't understand the error message.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But in your answer, I guess `temp` should be before `dir1` and `SR0a` should be before `temp`?

Comment: I edited the sorting of `temp`/`dir1` and `SR0a`/`temp`. Thanks for your answer and your time to investigate into the sorting algorithm of [tag:find].

Answer (score 1):

This find should work:

```
find . -path ./temp -prune -o -iname "*file*" -type f -exec cp '{}' temp/ \;
```

`-path ./misc -prune -o` is used to skip `./temp` directory while copying files to temp folder.

**Your `find` command is also finding `./temp/*file*` files and trying to copy them also into `./temp` folder.**

Answer (score 0):

> It is **caused by the find** that is trying to **copied to it self**.

- Pipe output using `while` to separate with `find` command
- Use `cp` with the option: `-frpvT` for match with file/dir target path
- Print the `realpath` of the ouput file, see if the file path are the same.

```
find . -iname "*file*" | while read -r f; do echo cp -frpvT "$(realpath $f)" "/temp/$f"; done
```

If so, then correct the file path, when it is done then you can remove the `echo` from the command.